# EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590

Tags: linux, ext4

### system info

```
root@steveguan-1:~# uname -a
Linux steveguan-1 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@steveguan-1:~# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

### action which i made cause the problem

i imported a vmware instance in to parallel and after parallel translate the vmware instance to an object ended with an postfix of .pvm it got this problem.

### phenomenon

i can not run `docker ps` in my vm and it failed with following message

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

### things i've tried

i tried to start docker it failed with below

```
root@steveguan-1:~# systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and the details looks below

```
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Aug 29 22:28:13 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 29 22:28:13 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 29 22:28:13 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Aug 29 22:28:13 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
```

i googled and follow the instruction of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089310/how-to-resolve-service-start-limit-hit, and `systemctl restart docker` it also failed and i typed `systemctl status docker` i got much detailed error message like below

```
Aug 29 22:36:35 steveguan-1 dockerd[3050]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: open /etc/docker/daemon.json: bad message
Aug 29 22:36:35 steveguan-1 kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2495068: comm dockerd: iget: checksum invalid
Aug 29 22:36:35 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 29 22:36:35 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 29 22:36:35 steveguan-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

although i've google a lot there are no results matched `kernel: EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590` accurately.

what's more, when i type `dmesg` it show error logs like below

```
[ 3808.842375] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2493025: comm cloud-id: iget: checksum invalid
[ 3808.843199] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2493025: comm cloud-id: iget: checksum invalid
[ 3808.844807] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2492995: comm cloud-id: iget: checksum invalid
[ 3808.845285] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2492995: comm cloud-id: iget: checksum invalid
[ 3808.845848] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2492809: comm cloud-id: iget: checksum invalid
[ 3808.846202] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_lookup:1590: inode #2492809: comm cloud-id: iget: checksum invalid
```

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `iget: checksum invalid` message means that your filesystem is corrupted. You should run e2fsck on it.

Comment: And as always, before running `e2fsck`, the filesystem should be unmounted. Some filesystem types may be checkable while the filesystem is active, but ext4 is not one of them.